# Highchart : Unable to populate data from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I was trying to learn highchart but when I am trying to populate the data from JSON it is not working fine. But I hardcode the data it works fine. So , I think I am doing some mistake while calling the JSON.

My JSON looks like :--

```
[{
"data": ["11-Aug 12:03", "11-Aug 12:45", "11-Aug 13:13", "11-Aug 13:53", "11-Aug 14:03", "11-Aug 14:33", "11-Aug 14:54", "11-Aug 15:17", "11-Aug 15:49", "11-Aug 16:07", "11-Aug 17:00", "11-Aug 17:33"]
}, {
 "data": [23987, 24784, 25899, 255, 25897, 25668, 24114, 23899, 224987, 25111, 25899, 23]
}, {
"data": [12.4, 4.56, 3.8, 1.2, 11, 12.3, 5.67, 7.65, 34.5, 12.78, 10.5, 2.8]
}]
```

Adding whole code :--

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Job Status'
    },

    xAxis: [{
        categories: [],
        crosshair: true
    }],
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {

            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Transaction Count',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },
        opposite: true

    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Time',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} min',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        }

    }, { // Tertiary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        labels: {

            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        opposite: true
    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        x: 80,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 55,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Rainfall',
        type: 'column',
        yAxis: 1,
        data: []

   },  {
        name: 'Temperature',
        type: 'spline',
        data: []

    }]

    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/TestQuartz/json/highdefault.json", function(json) {
        options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
        options.series[0] = json[1];
        options.series[1] = json[2];
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
});
```

I am unable to create a JSFiddle to show the live example.

Can you please help in where I am doing wrong while calling the data from JSON.

Regards

Comment: do you get any error message?

Comment: It Says unexpected identifier where the getJSON function is called.

Comment: what is the previous line before getJSON? I think you forgot a coma at the end.

Comment: Could you paste your whole code which you use?

Comment: Hi .. I have added the complete code .

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/2021935/sebastian-bochan .. Can you help me with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax of code is incorrect. Morefer you run highcharts two times. Fixed code:

```
$(function () {
var options = {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy',
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Job Status'
    },

    xAxis: [{
        categories: [],
        crosshair: true
    }],
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {

            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Transaction Count',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },
        opposite: true

    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Time',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} min',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        }

    }, { // Tertiary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        labels: {

            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        opposite: true
    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        x: 80,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 55,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Rainfall',
        type: 'column',
        yAxis: 1,
        data: []

    }, {
        name: 'Temperature',
        type: 'spline',
        data: []

    }]
};



    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/TestQuartz/json/highdefault.json", function (json) {
        options.xAxis[0].categories = json[0]['data'];
        options.series[0] = json[1];
        options.series[1] = json[2];
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your Help. There are 2 issues with it . X axis is taking deafault value of 1 2 3 and not from the JSON  like  11-Aug 12:03 and other issue that both graphs are coming as Line . One should be ideally Bar.

Comment: I updated my example, in the xAxis you should refer to xAxis[0], because you define array of xAxis object.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sebastian ... Sorry to ask for more but is it possible to have one of graph as Bar Chart and not both as Line chart ? Say the value which is 2nd in JSON like 23987 should be in Bar

Comment: Add a line for example: options.series[1].type = 'column';

Comment: I tried adding that but if I add any forced series it results in only 1 chart and other chart vanishes .$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/TestQuartz/json/highdefault.json", function (json) {
        options.xAxis[0].categories = json[0]['data'];
        options.series[0] = json[1];
        options.series[1] = json[2];
  options.series[1].type = 'column';
  options.series[0].type = 'spline';
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

Comment: Honestly this is unclear, so when you call these lines then types of series are not applied?

Comment: Types of series are getting applied but only one chart appears . Like only series 1 appear and series 2 disappears as soon as we add options.series[1].type = 'column';  or options.series[0].type = 'column';

Comment: I set these lines: options.xAxis[0].categories = json[0]['data'];
        options.series[0] = json[1];
        options.series[1] = json[2];
        options.series[0].type = 'column';
        options.series[1].type = 'spline'; and then I received two series with two different types. How can I replicate your issue?

Comment: I think I got the issue . There is so much diff in the value of 2 series that one is not appearing. If I reduce the value it appears fine . I was expecting it to be 2 axes Y chart where  but  I think it is taking value only from one axis ..

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-dual-axes/  but somehow the right and left Y axis are getting measured only on one scale not 2 diff scale

Comment: Set [alignTicks](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks) as false in chart object.

Comment: Im confused what is wrong, could you take a screenshot and mark what is incorrect and how it should be printed?